# Android emulator looks weird. Rendered with only 4 colors

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is how the Android emulator looks on my machine:

[4 color emulator](http://i51.tinypic.com/33ek0fp.jpg)

It worked great until I re-installed my computer a couple of days ago. AFAIR the last installation worked right out of the box, but something is obviously missing this time since the emulator can't render itself properly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If it helps, I'm running Fedora 15 and Ubuntu 11.04 (same problem on both) on an Asus UL30VT with the following chipsets:

Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210M] (rev a2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug related to scaling](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18299). If you scale the emulator window between 0.5 and 1.0, you get this effect. It should be fixed in the next Android tools release. In the meantime, either don't scale or scale it below 0.5.

Comment: Thanks! Strange that I didn't have this problem before. I've always scaled the emulator to make it fit on my screen.